# how to to set chat box based on user id using css

Tags: css, chat

i am developing chat application. i need to show user name who ever entering the message i need to display the message and user id in the chat box.

if user enter single letter in that time i need to show user id how much length is the i need to display. but i am not able display user id going to outside

```css
.t {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  text-align: right;
      padding-top: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: right;
  font-size: 12px;
     margin-bottom: 7px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

.t::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.t::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  right: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  clear: both;
  
}

.t {
  clear: right;
}

.t img {
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}
.t .username {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #8e0035;
  top: 4px;
  right: 10px;
}


.t .message{
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="t">
  <span class="username">kranthi</span>
  <span class="message">This is a very long message, as you can see it will be placed in multiple lines..This is a very long message, as you can see it will be placed in multiple lines.</span>
</div>

<div class="t">
  <span class="username">kranthi</span>
  <span class="message">thanks</span>
</div>

<div class="t">
  <span class="username">27535635496</span>
  <span class="message">1</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change position absolute to position relative to the username class, and then add display block to it so the message goes under the id. Also remove top and right properties:

```
.t .username {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #8e0035;
}
```